# how to enable keras fit() multiprocessing properly?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

when I run `fit()` with `multiprocessing=True` i always get a deadlock and the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended.
```

how to run it properly?

Since it says "`tf.data`", i wonder if transforming my data into this format will make multiprocessing work. What specifically is meant/how to convert it?

my dataset: (reproducable)

```
Input_shape, labels =(20,4), 6
LEN_X.LEN_Y = 20000.3000 
train_X,train_Y = np.asarray([np.random.random(Input_shape) for x in range(LEN_X )]), np.random.random((LEN_X ,labels))
validation_X,validation_Y = np.asarray([np.random.random(Input_shape) for x in range(LEN_Y)]), np.random.random((LEN_Y,labels))
sampleW = np.random.random((LEN_X ,1))
```

Answer (score -1):

[The multiprocessing doesn't accelerate the model itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620551/confusion-about-multiprocessing-and-workers-in-keras-fit-generator-with-window). It only accelerates the data loading. And data loading delay is not a problem when all your data is already in-memory.

You could still use multiprocessing, however, but you must make sure that the underlying dataset is thread-safe and you have to carefully craft the data pipeline. That is quite time consuming. So, instead I suggest you speed up the model itself.

For that, you should look into:

- changing all except last layer activations to RELU.
- tweaking batch size. (optimal number depends on your hardware, and is almost always [less than or equal to 32](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?s=20))
- using [Batch normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization) to speed up convergence.
- using higher learning rate (be careful not to overdo this step).
- if you need faster convolutions, consider using [Kaggle notebooks](https://www.kaggle.com/notebooks) or [vast.ai](https://vast.ai/) for GPU-enabled computations.
- last but not least, try using a simpler, smaller model.

---

Comment down here if you have any additional questions.
Cheers.

Comment: I've noticed that for Deep-Mind's AlphaZero (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01815.pdf), they used mini-batches of size 4096. Is that just them flexing their computer power on us, or is it an exception to the <=32 rule?

Comment: @Arkleseisure that's a good question. I'm not sure but maybe they used the results of a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08741)  that advocated a huge batch size in the very same year. Reinforcement learning is *very* hard to get right, we don't even know  how to find correct batch sizes in general, yet.