# What causes tensorflow to deadlock in the first epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle

I've been playing around with Tensorflow in Kaggle. It works fine until I enable multiprocessing, and then it deadlocks in the first epoch, just printing

```
Epoch 1/100
```

and then stalling.

There's a public MWE [here](https://www.kaggle.com/mohanganesalingam/diagnose-keras-deadlock-mwe). If you remove `use_multiprocessing=True` from the `model.fit_generator` on the last line, it works fine. I would be very grateful if anyone had any idea what was causing the deadlock & how I might be able to work around it.

Comment: I've also faced it too. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622603/9215780) is a discussion, probably you already encounter

Comment: Are you facing it only on the kaggle platform? Is it ok for you in colab or your local machine?

Comment: @Mohan, Can you please let us know  on which platform are you facing issue?

Comment: I've only tried on kaggle, I'm afraid. My main PC died and I don't have a machine set up for running tensorflow on sensibly right now, so I'm restricted to browser-based code for a while.